# Function returning 2 types based on input in Perl. Is this a good approach?

Tags: perl

i have designed a function which can return 2 different types based on the input parameters

```
ex: &Foo(12,"count")   -> returns record count from DB for value 12  
    &Foo(12,"details") -> returns resultset from DB for value 12 in hash format
```

My question is is this a good approach? in C# i can do it with function overload.

Comment: Does it make the code more complicated than necessary and/or hard to maintain or use correctly? If any part is true then -- *I would not* consider it a good approach.

Comment: Yes I understand. But I want to keep it simple as possible hence was trying this approach. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. Are these the only two modes or are there more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please think what part of your code gets easier by saying

```
Foo(12, "count")
```

instead of

```
Foo_count(12)
```

The only case I can think of is when the function name ("count") itself is input data. And even then do you probably want to perform some validation on that, maybe by means of a function table lookup.

Unless this is for an intermediate layer that just takes a command name and passes it on, I'd go with two separate functions.

Also, the implementation of the Foo function would look at the command name and then just split into a private function for every command anyway, right?

Answer (score 1):

additionally you might consider the want to make foo return the details if you wanted a list.

```
return wantarray ? ($num, @details) : $num;
```

Comment: If you're going to return an array, it's generally preferable to make all items in the array of the same type (i.e., just data items rather than a count and then data items). That goes double in this case, since the caller can get the count of items simply by evaluating the returned array in scalar context, so you gain nothing by returning it along with the array.